# Compact property

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to prove that if $\Omega$ is complete metric space, $\mathcal{F}$ is Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\Omega$, then for any positive $\varepsilon$ there is a compact set $\mathit{K}$, that $\mathbb{P}(\mathit{K})>1-\varepsilon$. I don't know where to start. I would be very grateful for help

Comment: You need separability of $\Omega$ or at least separable support of $P$. Otherwise it's not true. See Billigsley, Convergence of probab. measures

Comment: @Botnakov please tell me which page I can see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

Billingsley - Convergence of probability measures (1999, Wiley)

See p.8, Theorem 1.3 and Problem 1.12, p.13

Comment: oh, I realized that this statement is not true, thanks. But is there any counterexample to prove the claim is false?

Comment: @NickNiceday, hint: as you have complete metric space, in order to find counterexample  it's necessary and sufficient to find a mesure in complete metric space such that it has not separable support, but it's another question.